# How can I write a SQL query to map rows into columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following query from a database,

```
SELECT propertyname,propertyvalue,value, 
FROM db
```

which returns

```
| propertyname       | propertyvalue  | value    | 
+--------------------+----------------+----------+
| AnimalNumber       | 1              | 1.3      |   
| Group              | 1              | 1.3      |
| TimePoint          | 24 days        | 1.3      |
| Treatment method   | vehicle        | 1.3      |
| Treatment Conc     | 0              | 1.3      |
| AnimalNumber       | 2              | 0.5      |   
| Group              | 3              | 0.5      |
| TimePoint          | 7 days         | 0.5      |
| Treatment method   | vehicle        | 0.5      |
| Treatment Conc     | 0              | 0.5      |
```

We can see it's the case that multiple rows map to the same 'value' datapoint. Really, it should be the case that each of those 5 properties (animal number, group, time point, treatment method, treatment conc) should be columns and the first 5 data points should be condensed into a single row with a value=1.3. In other words, it should be something like

```
| AnimalNumber | Group | TimePoint | Treatment method | Treatment Conc  | value
+--------------+-------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+------+
| 1            | 1     | 24 days   | vehicle          | 0               | 1.3  |          
| 2            | 3     |  7 days   | vehicle          | 0               | 0.5  |
```

Also note that it is not necessarily the case that there is a 1-1 mapping to value, multiple combinations of animal number, group, timepoint, treatment method, and treatment conc can map to to the same value. So grouping by value I do not believe is the proper approach. Also note that all data provided here is, of course, fabricated and not real.

Comment: it depends from the db you are using. Try to look for PIVOT statement

Comment: If there are edge-cases relating to your last paragraph then you ought to include sample data that demonstrates those edge-cases; because otherwise it looks like grouping by `value` is the method to use (and you need to show us why we shouldn't and describe an alternative logic that we should use instead).

Answer (score 0):

one way is to group by value :

```
select max(propertyvalue) filter(where propertyname='AnimalNumber') AnimalNumber
      , max(propertyvalue) filter(where propertyname='TimePoint') TimePoint
      , max(propertyvalue) filter(where propertyname='Treatment method') "Treatment method"
      , max(propertyvalue) filter(where propertyname='Treatment Conc') "Treatment Conc"
      , max(propertyvalue) filter(where propertyname='Group') "Group"
from tablename
group by value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT(
  MAX(propertyvalue)
  FOR propertyname IN (
    'AnimalNumber' AS animalnumber,
    'Group' AS "GROUP",
    'TimePoint' AS TimePoint,
    'Treatment method' AS TreatementMethod,
    'Treatment Conc' AS TreatmentConc
  )
)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( propertyname, propertyvalue, value ) AS
SELECT 'AnimalNumber',     '1',       1.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Group',            '1',       1.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TimePoint',        '24 days', 1.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Treatment method', 'vehicle', 1.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Treatment Conc',   '0',       1.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AnimalNumber',     '2',       0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Group',            '3',       0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TimePoint',        '7 days',  0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Treatment method', 'vehicle', 0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Treatment Conc',   '0',       0.5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | ANIMALNUMBER | GROUP | TIMEPOINT | TREATEMENTMETHOD | TREATMENTCONC |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0.5 | 2 | 3 | 7 days | vehicle | 0 |
> | 1.3 | 1 | 1 | 24 days | vehicle | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cc362e69a5004102668963847c8423ae)*

Comment: This looks like it's close to working. However, the view that I showed actually had a where clause in it too that wasn't shown. The original was actually SELECT propertyname,propertyvalue,value, 
FROM db WHERE study = 'a' when I include the WHERE clause it throws the error, ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @Evan Works for me (although your sample data does not have a `study` column so I had to add it). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a650f77a8788b5a6ed5e2366cb4ce58)